# Compiler error 2039

Tags: .net, c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I am getting quite confused as to where I am getting this compiler error from. If anyone could help I would be very grateful. Here is the the error (I have 16 cases of it):

```
Error 6 error C2039: 'ToInt16' : is not a member of 'System::String'    c:\users\****.****\documents\visual studio 2005\projects\cpas1\cpas1\Form1.h    1265
```

and here is the a line of code affected:

```
 part1Quantity = this->txtPartQuantity1->Text->ToInt16(0);
```

Comment: Are you sure you copied/pasted the correct lines? The code line does not contain a call to `ToInt16`.

Comment: My bad, I have changed it now although it is  the same compiler error. Thank you for notifying me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`Convert.ToInt16`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/basyfs27.aspx) (with C++ example).

Answer (score 2):

.NET string doesn't have a ToInt16 method.

If you are doing something similar in c# and using string.ToInt16, chances are it is implemented as an extension method.

extension methods cannot be called as object member functions from managed C++

Comment: I'm using [this](http://www.functionx.com/vcnet/xml/readwrite.htm) tutorial if this helps.